# Why am I unable to write a value into a blank CSV file? Nil error

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a total of 7 columns with 6 columns initially filled out in a CSV file that I'm writing. When I try to populate the 7th column with data, I keep running into this error:

```
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<
```

Why do I keep running into this error? I should be able to write values into a 'nil'/blank space on a CSV file. Below is my code:

```
#Finds two records in the database
accounts = Account.find(1,2)
spammer_status = []

#Makes a call into the akismet API and populates spammer_status array with
#true or false values if the person is a spammer or not.
accounts.each do |accounts| 
  spammer_status << client.comment_check(accounts.last_seen_ip, nil,
                       :comment_author => accounts.name,
                       :comment_author_email => accounts.email,
                       :comment_author_url => accounts.url,
                       :comment_content => accounts.about)
end

#Changes the values from booleans to strings
spammer_status.map! { |value| value.to_s }

#Populates the initial 6 columns from the database values
CSV.open("/var/local/openhub/current/script/akismet_results.csv","w") do |row|
  row << ["id",
          "name",
          "email",
          "url",
          "description",
          "last seen ip",
          "spammer status"]
  accounts.each do |accounts|
    row << [accounts.id,
            accounts.name,
            accounts.email,
            accounts.url,
            accounts.about,
            accounts.last_seen_ip]
  end
end


#Attempts to populate the 7th column, nil error
CSV.foreach("/var/local/openhub/current/script/akismet_results.csv", headers:true) do |row|
 # binding.pry
  row[6] << spammer_status.shift
end
```

What am I doing wrong here? The error is on the foreach part of the program. All I want to do is to iterate a row at a time and then add the string converted booleans to the correct column. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Why can't you write the extra column at the same time that you write the first 6?

Comment: I tried doing this but because my spammer_status is an array, it will write everything that's in it into the 7th column. Basically, it will have a 7th column that will have [true,false] as the value.

Comment: Then shift the value off spammer_status, as you are trying in your second loop

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `<<` to a `nil` object. `row[6]` is nil. I believe you just want to assign a value to `row[6]` or if you want to use `<<`, just do it to `row` itself.

```
CSV.foreach("/var/local/openhub/current/script/akismet_results.csv", headers:true) do |row|
 # binding.pry
  row[6] = spammer_status.shift
  # or you could do row << spammer_status.shift
end
```

Comment: Nobita,Thanks for the quick reply. This is almost there but not quite. The last part of my CSV object looks like this "last seen ip":"xx.xxx.xxx.xxx" "spammer status":nil nil:"true">. The last two values don't write to the csv because they are nil.

Comment: I don't understand your problem.

Comment: Hey Nobita, I was trying to say that because of the implementation, spammer_status has a value of nil and true is trying to be written to a nil column, hence it doesn't write. I eventually figured it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured this issue out by refactoring my code. I have to admit that the above variation was not written very well. By extracting the spam status as a method and then creating a method call when the CSV is written, I was able to make the functionality work.

```
def is_spam?(account)
  spammer_status = client.comment_check(account.last_seen_ip, nil,
                                      :comment_author => account.name,
                                      :comment_author_email => account.email,
                                      :comment_author_url => account.url,
                                      :comment_content => account.about)
  spammer_status.to_s
end

CSV.foreach("/var/local/openhub/current/script/akismet_results.csv","a", headers: true) do |row|
    row << [account.id,
            account.name,
            account.email,
            account.url,
            account.about,
            account.last_seen_ip,
            is_spam?(account)]
  end
```